# Configure Bind to return always SERVFAIL

Tags: dns, bind

For testing purposes need to configure the Bind to return always SERVFAIL. Until know the only thing that I managed to do, was to receive back only refused.

Is it something like this possible? What is the "correct" way to do it in order to have minimum delay?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but look at the RPZ feature of bind, it may allow you to do what you need (but why do you need to return SERVFAIL in the first place? kind of strange...): https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#response-policy-zone-rpz-rewriting

Comment: Thank you for your answer Patrick. Unfortunatelly I have many options with the RPZ but SERVFAIL it's not one :). I need this because the client is behaving differently in case it receives SERVFAIL.

Comment: Any kind of misconfigured server should reply SERVFAIL so one has to find the shortest/smartest/simplest amount of bad configuration you would need to have bind always misbehave. On a second though, DNSdist is maybe a better fit for your need. See `RCodeAction` on https://dnsdist.org/rules-actions.html, that should allow to reply SERVFAIL how much you need...